# Oauth Bigcommerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, bigcommerce

I'm getting error "**Invalid client id**" while authorization my rails app with bigcommerce api.

omniauth.rb file is

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :bigcommerce, 
                 'CLIENT_ID', 
                 'CLIENT_SECRET',
                {
                scope: "users_basic_information store_v2_products store_v2_information store_v2_content",
                client_options: {
                site: 'https://login.bigcommerce.com'
                }
            }
end
```

and in the second api call which is post request like

```
response = HTTParty.post(
        'https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token',
        {body: {
          client_secret: auth['credentials']['token'].client.secret,
          client_id: auth['credentials']['token'].client.id,
          code: params[:code],
          scope: params[:scope],
          grant_type: :authorization_code,
          redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3001/auth/bigcommerce/callback",
          context: 'params[:Store_hash]'
          },
          headers: {
            'Content-Type'=> 'application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded'
          }
        }
      )
```

getting "Invalid client id" in the response of post request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is fairly straight forward. Please see the Bigcommerce docs in regards to locating your client id: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/registration